# yam.platform.getLoginStatus invokes callback without response.user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yammer

When I call yam.platform.getLoginStatus ***right after*** logging in using yam.platform.login (shows the popup etc.) I get a different object passed to the callback than when the user is already logged in. Specifically, the 'user' field is missing on the LoginStatus response object, otherwise it looks the same as far as I can see.

I have the following controller for a 'login with yammer' area on my angular app:

```
function YammerLoginController($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
    $scope.userName = "-";
    $scope.login = function () {
        yam.platform.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log("logged in");
            }
            refreshLoginStatus();
        });
    }

    refreshLoginStatus(); // initialize values
    function refreshLoginStatus() {
        yam.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            console.dir(response);
            if (response.authResponse) {
                if (response.user) {
                    console.log("YammerLogin: Logged in as " + response.user.full_name);
                    console.dir(response);
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
                        $scope.userName = response.user.full_name;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    console.log("WTF Yammer API!"); // THIS HAPPENS.
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("YammerLogin: Not logged in.");
                $('#loggedInView').popover("hide");
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
                    $scope.userName = "-";
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

When the controller is created it already queries the current login status using the `refreshLoginStatus` function. If a yammer user is already logged in the app will display the user name and a logout button on the page (done with ng-show="isLoggedIn"). If the user is not logged in, a login button will be shown instead. When the user clicks on that login button, the `$scope.login` function will be called, invoking `yam.platform.login` and, if successful, calls `refreshLoginStatus` again in order to retrieve and set the user's name. In this scenario, the object returned from both, `login` and `getLoginStatus` do not contain the user information like in the 'user is already logged in' scenario. I tried calling the SDK-API again after some timeout, but apparently the response is cached - I always get the same. Only refreshing the whole page clears out the current response, querying the status again and receiving a 'complete' response object.

I thought it could be a scoping problem, but by now I'm not sure whether it's a problem in the SDK itself. :S

EDIT: I kind of found a solution, which however only gives me worse problems. Apparently the request is indeed cached. A refresh can be forced by using 'force refresh' on `yam.platform.getLoginStatus(callback, [forceRefresh])`. This, however gives me the following error on the browser console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.yammer.com/platform/login_status.json?client_id=2h4U2Hndg5kdWQ8xxxxxx.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Basically, the SDK fails to getLoginStatus, completely, and reports this back to my code as 'no connection'. I'm not sure what's worse... or, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that is just an inconsistency in the yam.platform.getLoginStatus API or the corresponding Yammer service called. If the user logs in, you get the user info, if he is alreaddy logged in, you don't get it. That is just weird but apparently can't be helped.

However, I solved this problem by simply always getting the user login data using a separate REST service call on [/users/current.json](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/userscurrentjson) once the session is authenticated (once I have the token from getLoginStatus).